# UIPageView - curling is slow

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uiimage, page-curl

I've got an magazine app which contains big images. When I want to turn over the page there is a big delay before the page will be turned. So I try to cache previous, current and next page but without effect. I think I'm adding viewControllers but those are only getting images files without drawing. Is there any way how to draw images in background before page's turned? There's some code:

MagazineViewController:

```
- (void)loadViews {
NSInteger pagesCount = [_pages count];

if (currentPage == 0) currentPage = 1;
if ([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled]) return;

if (_curPage == nil) {
    _curPage = [[PageViewController alloc] init];
    PageView *pageView = [[PageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    [pageView setPages:_pages];
    [pageView setPage:currentPage];
    [pageView setMagazineID:_magazineID];
    [pageView buildFrames];
    //[pageView setHidden:YES];

    [_curPage setView:pageView];
    //[_flipper addSubview:magazineView];

    [pageView release];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kPageLoadedNotification object:nil];
}

if (_prevPage == nil) {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
        _prevPage = [[PageViewController alloc] init];
        PageView *pageView = [[PageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

        [pageView setPages:_pages];
        [pageView setPage:currentPage - 1];
        [pageView setMagazineID:_magazineID];
        [pageView buildFrames];

        [_prevPage setView:pageView];
        //[_pageViewController.view addSubview:_prevPage.view];

        [pageView release];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kPageLoadedNotification object:nil];
    }
}

if (_nextPage == nil) {
    if (currentPage + 1 <= pagesCount) {
        _nextPage = [[PageViewController alloc] init];
        PageView *pageView = [[PageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

        [pageView setPages:_pages];
        [pageView setPage:currentPage + 1];
        [pageView setMagazineID:_magazineID];
        [pageView buildFrames];

        [_nextPage setView:pageView];
        //[_pageViewController.view addSubview:_nextPage.view];

        [pageView release];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kPageLoadedNotification object:nil];
    }
}
```

Method "buildFrame" just making position and rect of images and doing "[self addSubView:image]". (self = view of page)

Image drawing:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   [super drawRect:rect];

   if (_image != nil) [_image drawInRect:rect];
}
```

I know about one method how to do but I think It's bad method. Just making previous and next view hidden and when I start to turning set view visible. So is there any other way how to load images and speed up turning? Thx for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got solution... load prev and next view, add them to parent view and send them back with method sendSubviewToBack. Awesome!